# How to set an environment variable in crontab using Chef?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a recipe that sets jobs to run from an EC2 instance's crontab. Here's an example of a recipe I'm running:

```
cron "examplejob" do
 minute "0"
 hour "2"
 command "job"
 user "job"
end
```

This works great. In addition to this cron job, I also want to set a few environment variables in crontab. Reading [this](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Cron), it seems like it should be possible using the "path" attribute. However, I am unable to find a specific example of how to implement this.

I tried:

```
cron "env" do
 path "MY_VAR=/path/for/variable"
end
```

But this does not work. How can I get the environment variables to be set at the top of the crontab? Any insight appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer you're looking for is the `environment` attribute, which expects a Hash object.

See http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#arguments and https://github.com/opscode/chef/commit/96ef7d770a7d898fdce097c7fda9039abf7bf485

In order to set a custom environment variable, you would write the following

```
my_env_vars = {"env1" => "val1", "env2" => "val2"}    

cron "env" do
 environment my_env_vars
 command "/path/to/job -someoption"
end
```

Chef will iterate over your hash and you should see the following in `sudo crontab -e`

```
# Chef Name: env
env1=val1
env2=val2
* * * * * /path/to/job -someoption
```

Quick note: On my machine with Chef 10.16.2, passing in the hash directly within the `cron` stanza will return a syntax error. `syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'` Not that you should pass in the hash directly anyway, but I figured it was worth mentioning since someone else might repeat my same mistake. As soon as you throw the hash into a variable, everything works as expected.

Comment: I read your answer, glossed over your note, then immediately made the same mistake passing in the hash directly. It also works if you wrap hash syntax in parens, like so: `environment({'env1' => 'val1'})`

Answer (score -1):

Data Bags with a top level key corresponding to your environment. The Opscode wiki has a quick and to the point description of how you could do this. [Data Bags and Environments](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Environments#Environments-DataBagsandEnvironments) As per your earlier example:

```
cron "[node.chef_environment]" do
 path "bag_item[node.chef_environment]["path_for_variable"]"
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to get fancy you can use [Templates](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Templates) with your data bags and just call the template you within the recipe. This would apply when you have the crontab calling the same function just with a different variable. That way you can edit the template whenever you need to and it would reflect across environments.

Comment: You're conflating the Chef concept of environment with the shell concept of environment. OP wants to set environment variables as you would do at the top of a crontab--not use Chef environment attributes in the cron resource.